# How can I use the data of axios's response outside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

my current function looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const GET_LOCATIONS = 'GET_LOCATIONS';

export function fetchLocals() {

    const request = axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api')
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    return {
        type: GET_LOCATIONS, 
        payload: request
    };
}
```

I want to be able to get the `response.data` outside of this so I can access its information and publish them!

Answer (score 0):

Just return `response.data` from the `.then` handle, and it will be fine:

```
export function fetchLocals() {

    const request = axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api')
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });

    return {
        type: GET_LOCATIONS, 
        payload: request
    };
}
```

Now you can call the function like this:

```
fetchLocals().payload
  .then(data => {
    // `data` will be `response.data` here
  });
```

Note that a `Promise.reject` call is required in the `catch` handle to make the subsequent handlers identify a rejected promise.

Comment: I dont understand what happens in the second part!

Comment: @S.N -- what do you mean by _second part_?

Comment: I mean calling the function that part I dont undertand how it should be, do you mena in my reducers?

Comment: @S.N -- I don't much understand ReactJS, and my answer has nothing to do with it as well. `fetchLocals()` returns an object, and the `payload` key points to a promise. So you can use the way I mentioned in my answer to access `response.data` outside the `fetchLocals()` without any issue.

Comment: is there any way to get that through the payload?